# Active Directory: logon issue between different domains and management issue

Tags: dns, active-directory, authentication, windows-domain

I have a simple network composed by a router (no firewall) and two domain controllers for two different domains and everything is virtualized under VMWare Workstation Pro 16.

The two domains are `example.test` and `experiment.test` in the same forest `example.test` and the FQDN for the domain controllers are **DC.example.test** and **DC.experiment.test**

These domain controllers are on separate subnets and can see each other’s thanks to the router (it is just a router, no firewall). The computers run Windows Server 2019 and they have been configured practically in the same manner: they have been created from the same Sysprep image.

**DC.example.test** is also DNS server for its domain as well as **DC.experiment.test** is DNS server for its domain and they are configured with static IP:

`192.168.10.1/24` the first and `192.168.20.1/24` the second.

Both domain controllers are configured for also making use of the DNS of the other. I have disabled firewall on both domain controllers.

I can ping without problem using the FQDN from both computers.

Here the strange behaviors:

1. if I try to login as Administrator to `example.test` domain from **dc.experiment.test**, I can do it without problems but if I try to do the opposite, i.e. to login as Administrator to `experiment.test` domain from **dc.example.test**, I get
   `The sign-in method you’re trying to use isn’t allowed. For more info, contact your network administrator.`
2. I’m not able to add **DC.example.test** to the Server Manager of **DC.experiment.test** and vice versa, getting the  error message `The metadata failed to be retrieved from the server, due to the following error: WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet.`

and the message `Target computer not accessible` in the All Servers view.

What did I do wrong?

**MORE**

1. I'm trying to log in from the initial logon screen and, I repeat, from DC.experiment.test I can but from DC.example.test I cannot;
2. WinRM service is running on both computers and it is set as Automatic for both;
3. everything on the router is allowed: it is just a router without any kind of block/filter; just for exclude that the issue was caused by the router, I have connected the two domain controllers directly on the same subnet, using a different VMnet and disabling the other NICs

Comment: @Pillsbury IT Doughboy Thanks for your reply. These are the answers (I've also edited the question, putting them in it):
1) I'm loggin in from the initial logon screen

2) WinRM service is running on both computers and it is set as Automatic for both

3) Everything on the router is allowed: it is just a router without any kind of block/filter; just for exclude that the issue was caused by the router, I have connected the two domain controllers directly on the same subnet, using a different VMnet and disabling the other NICs

Comment: @Pillsbury IT Doughboy Thanks for your time. One of the things I did was disabling Windows firewall as I said in the my question.
I do not logon via Remote Desktop but from the actual Windows logon screen.

Comment: @Pillsbury IT Doughboy Thanks for your time. I'll make some checks and let you know but I do not think that it is a trust problem since between two trees of the same forest is automatically created a transitive trust.

Comment: It's been a while for me with trusted domains really, but perhaps you can sign onto the other domain if its listed without joining it. That does sound more familiar to me now because I just recall the drop down showing for the other domain you could select and then log onto it. I do not think you have to join one from one domain to the other after all. It's been a while so I apologize. You might consider asking on ServerFault as someone there may know more quickly. If nothing is being blocked network traffic wise and the trusts are setup, it sounds like it should work but not sure. Good luck!

Comment: Try with workstations and not domain controllers. Or try it with non-domain controller servers both ways. I don't recall signing onto a DC as another domain user or admin though just in case that's the issue, try non-DC machines and see what results you get.